Inconsistent Bounding Box and Array Shapes When Querying Tiled Raster Data from PostGIS Using GDAL
I am using Python to query and visualize raster data stored in a PostGIS database. The raster data is tiled using -t auto during the import process. I have written a script to query the raster data for a given bounding box and for the whole raster. However, I am getting inconsistent results for the bounding box extents and array shapes, especially when querying different raster tables (deptho and so).
Here's how I'm importing the NetCDFs:
raster2pgsql -t auto -s 4326 -I -C -M -F NETCDF:"$NETCDF_FILE":$VARIABLE_NAME $TABLE_NAME > $SQL_FILE
psql -h $DB_HOST -U $DB_USER -d $DB_NAME -p $DB_PORT -f $SQL_FILE

import psycopg2
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import BytesIO

def query_raster(conn, table_name, band, min_lat, min_lon, max_lat, max_lon):
    try:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        query = f"""
        WITH bbox AS (
            SELECT ST_Transform(
                ST_MakeEnvelope({min_lon}, {min_lat}, {max_lon}, {max_lat}, 4326), 
                (SELECT ST_SRID(ST_BAND(rast, {band})) FROM {table_name} LIMIT 1)
            ) AS geom
        )
        SELECT ST_AsTIFF(ST_Union(ST_BAND(rast, {band})), 'GTiff')
        FROM {table_name}, bbox
        WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_BAND(rast, {band}), bbox.geom);
        """
        cur.execute(query)
        raster_data = cur.fetchone()[0]
        cur.close()
        return raster_data
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
        return None

def query_whole_raster(conn, table_name, band):
    try:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        query = f"""
        SELECT ST_AsTIFF(ST_Union(ST_BAND(rast, {band})), 'GTiff')
        FROM {table_name};
        """
        cur.execute(query)
        raster_data = cur.fetchone()[0]
        cur.close()
        return raster_data
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
        return None

def read_raster_from_memory(raster_data):
    memfile = BytesIO(raster_data)
    gdal.FileFromMemBuffer('/vsimem/temp.tif', memfile.read())
    dataset = gdal.Open('/vsimem/temp.tif')
    band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
    array = band.ReadAsArray()
    geotransform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
    gdal.Unlink('/vsimem/temp.tif')
    return array, geotransform

def plot_raster(array, geotransform, title="Clipped Raster Data"):
    min_lon = geotransform[0]
    max_lon = min_lon + geotransform[1] * array.shape[1]
    max_lat = geotransform[2]
    min_lat = max_lat + geotransform[5] * array.shape[0]

    extent = [min_lon, max_lon, min_lat, max_lat]
    print("Plotting Extent:", extent)
    print("Array Shape:", array.shape)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    plt.imshow(array, extent=extent, origin='upper', cmap='viridis')
    plt.colorbar(label='Raster Value')
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel("Longitude")
    plt.ylabel("Latitude")
    plt.savefig('bla.png')

try:
    min_lat = 63
    min_lon = -24
    max_lat = 67
    max_lon = -13

    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname="spatial_db",
        user="postgres",
        password=" ",
        host="localhost",
        port="5432"
    )

    for table_name in ['deptho', 'so']:
        band = 1

        raster_data = query_whole_raster(conn, table_name, band)
        if raster_data is not None:
            array, geotransform = read_raster_from_memory(raster_data)
            array = np.where(array == 9.9692100e+36, np.nan, array)
            plot_raster(array, geotransform)
        else:
            print("No raster data returned from the query.")
        
        raster_data = query_raster(conn, table_name, band, min_lat, min_lon, max_lat, max_lon)
        if raster_data is not None:
            array, geotransform = read_raster_from_memory(raster_data)
            array = np.where(array == 9.9692100e+36, np.nan, array)
            plot_raster(array, geotransform)
        else:
            print("No raster data returned from the query.")

except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", e)

finally:
    conn.close()

Problem
When I run the script, I get different results for the bounding box extents and array shapes for the two tables (deptho and so).
Table: deptho
Whole Raster:
Extent: [-49.041666666666664, 17.041666666666664, 50.95833333333334, 83.04166666666667]
Bounding Box:
Extent: [-28.708333333333332, -8.375, 57.375000000000014, 70.20833333333334]
Array Shape: (154, 244)

Table: so
Whole Raster:
Extent: [-180.04166666902196, 179.95835368074071, -80.04166666666664, 90.04166666666667]
Array Shape: (2041, 4320)
Bounding Box:
Extent: [-36.04165852911689, -12.041657172466042, 50.79166666666668, 76.95833333333334]
Array Shape: (314, 288)





Why am I getting different extents and array shapes when querying the deptho and so tables for the same bounding box? Both are in EPSG:4326.
I have written two functions:
query_whole_raster: Fetches the entire raster data for a given table and band.
query_raster: Fetches the raster data for a specified bounding box.
I then read the raster data into memory using GDAL and plot it using Matplotlib. I run these functions for two raster tables (deptho and so) and print the extents and array shapes.
What I Expected:
I expected the extents and array shapes to be consistent for both tables when querying the whole raster and when querying the raster for the same bounding box.
What Actually Happened:
The extents and array shapes are inconsistent between the two tables.
